# Animate UITableViewCell content with AutoLayout when cell appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` displaying cells. I am using Auto Layout. At some point, I add cells to a section of my tableView and I need to animate a subview of each cells as soon as the cells are visible.

I wrote the following method to animate the content of my cell:

```
- (void)animateWithPercentage:(NSNumber *)percentage
{
    self.progressViewWidthConstraint.constant = [percentage intValue];
    [self.progressView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f animations:^{
        [self.progressView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

The method works as expected but I don't know when to call it.

If I call it when `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called, I end up animating the whole layout of my cell because the cell did not layout itself before.

I also tried calling it in `layoutSubviews` but the animation is skipped. I guess at this point it is too early to animate anything.

Any idea where my method should be called?

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten this kind of animation to work by calling performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: in either awakeFromNib or didMoveToSuperview in the custom cell's class. It works even with a delay of 0, but it doesn't work if you just use performSelector. I've noticed that with this method, if some of the cells are off screen, they don't update until they are scrolled on, and the scrolling animation ends. You can get the animation to start as soon as the cell scrolls on screen, even while the scrolling animation is still in progress by using dispatch_async instead.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
            self.rightCon.constant = 150;
            [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:nil];
    });
}
```

Comment: I actually can't use awakeFromNib because of the cell recycling logic. Sometimes I need to perform my animations with cells that are recycled. But I'll try your technique in tableView:willDisplayCell: maybe it is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your method in -(void)didMoveToSuperview